# how to get multiple selected values from multiple select options php codeigniter?

Tags: php, html

I was trying to implement tag words selection using select2 for my project in codeigniter but I was unable to read or get the value of the the multiselect option I implemented using select2 available at https://github.com/select2/select2.
Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-lable">Select job categories.</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <select style="width:120%" class="form-control select2" name="job_category" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select job categories" style="width: 100%;">
           <option value="3">Civil</option>
           <option value="6">Electrical</option>
           <option value="15">Javascript</option>
           <option value="2">Programming</option>
           <option value="4">Networking</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included all necessary js(jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js and select2.full.min.js) & css(bootstrap.min.css & select2.min.css) files which I think are necessary for the select2 option to work properly in my project.

Can anyone help me get through this?
Any help is duly appreciated.

Comment: you are not getting job_category in your PHP script on form submit ? OR select js is not working ?

Comment: Any JS error showing in your browser console?

Comment: @AkshayP If I check the posted value using:    if(isset($_POST['job_category'])){
   die('set');
  } the output is set.

Comment: @woodykiddy no js error found using firebug

Comment: instead of if(isset($_POST['job_category'])){ die('set'); }  try, if(isset($_POST['job_category'])){ print_r($_POST['job_category']); } and tell me the result

Comment: @AkshayP Did what you said and it outputs the value of only the option which I selected last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `name="job_category"` to `name="job_category[]"`. This will post an array having values of selected options.

and in `PHP` you can get those values as :

```
 <?php
 foreach ($_REQUEST['job_category'] as $selectedOption)
     echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

When you want to get multiple selected options you should use `[]` in name attribute.

Comment: @AkshyaP: It works. In fact I'd tried both $_POST['job_category'] & CI's Input class $this->input->post('jobcategory') to loop through the posted values but they both showed error. Never knew $_REQUEST would work in such circumstances.

Comment: which method are you using to submit the form ? POST / GET ?

Comment: @AkshyaP: I am using POST all the while.